# First order PDE with three variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-pde

I know how to solve linear first order partial differential equations  with two independent variables using the charactereristics method.

My question is: How to solve firts order linear PDE if it contains three independent variables:
$$a(x,y,z)u_x+b(x,y,z)u_x+c(x,y,z)u_z=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to solve (with the characteristic method) first order linear PDE if it contains three independent variables:
$$a(x,y,z)u_x+b(x,y,z)u_x+c(x,y,z)u_z=0$$
Obviously, first learn a course about the characteristic method.

Then solve the characteristic ODE equations :
$$\frac{dx}{a(x,y,z)}=\frac{dy}{b(x,y,z)}=\frac{dz}{c(x,y,z)}$$
Solving $\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b(x,y,z)}{a(x,y,z)}\quad$ leads to an implicite solution : $\quad f(x,y,z)=C_1$

Solving $\quad \frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{c(x,y,z)}{a(x,y,z)}\quad$ leads to an implicite solution : $\quad g(x,y,z)=C_2$

The general solution of the PDE is:
$$u(x,y,z)=F\left(f(x,y,z), g(x,y,z)\right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of two variables.